# Office Web Apps - Word Cannot Read, But Can Edit

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps

On my instance of SharePoint 2010 that has multiple tenanted site collections, I have installed Office Web Apps. After having a few issues with the initial setup, I have the service applications setup and running, and I am able to open and edit Powerpoint and Excel files.

However, when I attempt to Open (For Viewing) Word files, I get an error: " Word Web App cannot open this document for viewing because of an unexpected error. To view this document, open it in Microsoft Word. Error Id: ".

After opening the ULS logs, I have found that the underlying error message looks like the below:

> 04/16/2013 09:34:45.20 ... Office Web Apps         Office Viewing Architecture     30gr    Unexpected   Unexpected exception in UnifiedCache.BeginRead System.ArgumentException: List 'cache' does  not exist at site with URL '`http://rootsite`'.     at  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetListByName(String strListName, Boolean  bThrowException)     at  Microsoft.Office.Web.Environment.Sharepoint.WacSharepointCacheOM.GetCacheDocLib(SPSite site)      at Microsoft.Office.Web.Environment.Sharepoint.WacSharepointCacheOM.GetCachedItem(SPSite  site, Guid documentSiteId, String versionRep, Guid variation)

Where `http://rootsite` is the core url of the tenanted web application. I believe the error stems from the fact that, at the time of configuring Office Web Apps, there was no Site Collection created for that URL. (As it is a tenanted configuration, I understand it is best practice to leave it this way, but correct me if I am wrong)

I will stress that I can Edit all document types (Word, Excel and PowerPoint), however I cannot open Word documents for reading. I have ensured that the Service Applications are setup and running correctly. I have also ensured that the OfficeWebApps Cache is configured correctly. The Temp directory locations at `C:\Windows\Temp\powerpointcache` and `C:\Windows\Temp\waccache` both exist on the server.

Does anybody know of a way to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out and the answer is not directly related to the install of Office Web Apps or the cache list issues as I first thought.

Word docs were actually not being opened because a setting in Central Admin needed to be changed. By default, the setting

> Central Administration->Application Management->Manage Web Applications->General Settings->Browser File Handling

is set to 'Strict'. If set to 'Permissive', the Word docs were then opened without errors.

There is more info on this setting here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8073.sharepoint-2010-and-2013-browser-file-handling-deep-dive.aspx